# Keep LaTeX longtable from starting on a new page?

Tags: longtable, page-breaking

I have a longtable in a section on my CV which keeps starting on a new page, resulting in a large white space after the section heading. I'd prefer the table to "break" part way through and fill the first page, rather than trying to keep the table together. I can't figure out how to make it do this.

In the .cls file, I have:

```
\definecolor{dateline}{gray}{0.5}
\definecolor{datecolor}{gray}{0.4}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{4em}}
\newcommand{\daterule}{\color{dateline}\vrule width 1pt}
\newcommand{\dateentry}[2]{{\leavevmode\color{datecolor}{#1}} & #2 \\ \noalign{\medskip}}
%\dimexpr(\textwidth - #1)\relax
\newenvironment{datetabular}[1]{%
    \begin{longtable}{@{}>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}p{#1}!{\daterule}p{\dimexpr(\linewidth - #1 - 1em)\relax}}%
}{%
    \end{longtable}%
}
```

There is then a section called "Service", where the entries look like this (I made a form called \serviceentry just to format the text into lines for the table):

```
\section{Service}
\begin{datetabular}{9em}
%
%DEPT AND UNIVERSITY SERVICE
%
\service{Department \& University Service}{%
\serviceentry{Marketing Committee Member}{X Department, University}{Spring 2023 - Present}

\serviceentry...
}
```

As a result, there is a huge space after the section heading (see pic)[image]

Comment: The problem is that longtable can only break between rows, and the p{} field counts as one row.  It is possible to mnually break a paragraph over two p{} fields.

Comment: Or it could be just too wide:  1em <3\tabcolsep.